# Chrome Dev Tools: How to auto set event listener breakpoints for a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In some situations,I need to debug a webpage crash bug, for example,execute the code below in the console of a https web page:

```
window.open("http://file.hackingfor.fun/camp/3/liuliang.zip")
```

The ideal situation is that a new tab would pop up and then begin to download the file in the url.
But actually, the new tab would exit instantly without any error infomation(the auto opened dev tool also exit, so I can't find anything in the console).

After longtime's effort,I finally figure out that it is a CORS problem.But it costs me a lot.

Is there any way to  auto set event listener breakpoints for a new tab to keep the dev tool open even after the window crash so that I can quickly figure out the problem( just set a window close breakpoint is enough for me)?

Comment: I don't think so but you can use `chrome://net-export`

Comment: @wOxxOm The error information would be in the console,so can `chrome://net-export` longing the console error?

Comment: In net-export you can inspect the requests. To view the console you would need to start Chrome with [logging enabled](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and inspect chrome_debug.log.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! I've tried start chrome with args as `chrome.exe --enable-logging --v=1` but nothing useful in chrome_debug.log until I close all chrome processes and start only one with this args.